# Compile multiple Ligo contracts at one go

Tags: ligo

I would like to compile all contracts in a folder at one go.

I tried
`"compile all": "docker run --rm -v \"$PWD\":\"$PWD\" -w \"$PWD\" ligolang/ligo:0.24.0 compile-contract contracts/*.ligo main > compiled/*.tz",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cd contracts
for i in *.ligo; do 
    docker run --rm -v \"$PWD\":\"$PWD\" -w \"$PWD\" \
        ligolang/ligo:0.24.0 compile-contract \ 
        contracts/$i main > compiled/$i.tz
done
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you explain what you mean by for i in  *.ls; Its not working and I'm trying to understand your code.

Comment: Also, I am trying this out, as a script in my package.json

Comment: i'm sorry, that was a type. it should be `*.ligo` of course. updating answer

Comment: I'm making some minor modifications so i can mark this as the answer: 

since $i is effectively the whole file name, you will end up with the extension printed twice.

so for a given contract.ligo, $i.ligo will print contract.ligo.ligo.tz

Comment: I also navigated inside the contracts folder to avoid having the path printed in the file name.